# want user will logout from shell on exit of bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting

I want, when a linux user exits from a shell script, that it  also logs out from the bash shell.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of starting the script normally, `exec` it instead. This will replace the login shell, so when the script finishes the user will be logged out.

Answer (score 4):

End your script with `kill -HUP $PPID`

$PPID is the process ID of the parent process.

Comment: `$PPID` might fail if the script is run from a subshell, e.g. bash login shell → another bash shell → this script. Also why `-9` and not `-HUP`?

Comment: kill -9 closes all processes it can without letting them close their file descriptors, freeing their memory, etc... I don't think it's a good idea if the script does any I/O.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Feeling a little bit destructive today ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you could use the script name **instead of the shell** in /etc/passwd.

The last entry in /etc/passwd (everything after the last colon) is the **shell** that is run when the user logs on.  By changing this to the name of your script, when the script ends, then by definition, so does the shell.

** Be very careful editing /etc/passwd however, as you could lock yourself out of your machine.  Apparently you can do this with

```
usermod --shell <script name> <user name>
```

which would be the safer way to make this change.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach may be to `source` the script instead of calling it directly, an `exit` statement in the script will then close the user shell:

```
$ cat exit_me.sh
#!/bin/bash
exit
```

and

```
$ source exit_me.sh
# or
$ . exit_me.sh
```

More info about `source` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).

Answer (score 0):

with kill ?

```
$ kill -HUP `ps -ef |grep $USER|grep bash|awk {'print $2'}`
```

Edit: as said in the comments, it works better with PPID

```
$ kill -HUP $PPID
```

Comment: There is a variable for that: $PPID

Comment: Yes, definitely use `$PPID`. Using `ps` in that way will log the user out of other sessions, too, which may be very undesirable.

Answer (score -3):

It is possible to do this if you include an EXIT at the end of your script, which tells the bash shell to terminate.

Comment: the exit will exit the current bash script, and not the bash of the user running it

Comment: no exit will terminate only that script not the bash shell

Comment: This will just exit the sub-shell where the script is executed and doesn't solve the question.